# Удаляются ли подписки объекта при удалении его из GeoObjectCollection

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

Если я загружаю на карту  некоторое количество  `Placemark`, навешиваю на каждое обработчик события. Потом требуется очистить карту, пользователь выбрал другой регион. Удаляю все объекты `removeAll` из `GeoObjectCollection` и загружаю новые `Placemark`.

Есть ощущение, что страница начинает «пухнуть» и подтормаживать.

Вопрос - нужно ли перед очисткой коллекции принудительно отсоединять все обрабочики событий?

Answer (score 2):

Добрый день. В API Яндекс.карт не автоматического удаления подписки на событий. То есть после удаления сущностей подписки останутся висеть в памяти.

 Это можно поправить только лишь явным удалением подписок. Но чтобы не хранить подписки на все объекты можно немного упростить код.

1. Можно завешивать подписки непосредственно GeoObjectCollection. Все стандартные события будут пробрасываться.
2. Можно создать группу событий через метод group().
   https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/IEventManager-docpage/#group

Примерно так:

```
this._eventsGroup = this._geoObjectCollection.events.group()
// Событий геообъектов внутри коллекции будут приходить 
.add('click', () => {
    // ...
});

// ...

this._eventsGroup.removeAll();
this._geoObjectCollection.removeAll();
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Принудительная очистка подписок непосредственно GeoObjectCollection спасла ситуацию.